# . I have a method (given below) that has a lot of queries. How can I optimize it?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a method (given below) that has a lot of queries. How can I optimize it?

```
def index
  @users = User.all
  @admin_users = User.where(role: 'admin')
  @call_users = User.where(role: 'call_user')
  @buy_users = User.where(role: 'buy_user')
  @blocked_users = User.where(role: 'blocked_user')
end
```

Answer (score 1):

All these depends upon how is the view page defined, if in the view page users can sort by different roles then it can written as

```
@users = User.where(role: params[:role])
```

Or if the goal is to display users with all these roles in view page, then you can pass the array of roles, which needs to be filtered out,.

```
@users = User.where(role: ['admin', 'paid_user', 'free_user', 'blocked_user'])
```

Answer (score 0):

> How can I optimize it?

Small question, big scope.

---

[**Enum**](http://edgeapi.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Enum.html)

Firstly, you **shouldn't** be defining `@user.role` with a string.

What happens if you get the string wrong, or you wish to *change* the role? You need to store the roles separately to your db, allowing you to *reference* them (with an `int`). This can be achieved with either an `enum` or `association`:

```
#app/models/user.rb
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  enum role: [:admin, :call_user, :buy_user, :blocked_user]
end
```

An `enum` will give you access to a number of `instance` & `class` methods to optimize your queries:

```
@user = User.find x

@user.admin?         #-> true
@user.call_user?     #-> false
@user.buy_user?      #-> false
@user.blocked_user?  #-> false

User.admin      #-> collection of admin users
User.call_user  #-> collection of call_user users
User.buy_user   #-> collection of buy_user users
```

In your case, it would get rid of the `where` clauses, allowing you to call:

```
def index
  @users         = User.all
  @admin_users   = User.admin
  @call_users    = User.call_user
  @buy_users     = User.buy_user
  @blocked_users = User.blocked_user
end
```

---

**ActiveRecord**

Secondly, you don't have lots of *queries*; you have lots of *definitions*.

I learnt from [`@Marek Lipka`](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1279683/marek-lipka) that `ActiveRecord` doesn't *query* when you define a variable, only when you output that variable in the view. It's called ["Lazy Loading"](http://www.theodinproject.com/ruby-on-rails/active-record-queries):

> `Active Record` queries return relations to be lazy. There's basically no reason to actually tell the database to execute a query until the very last possible minute.
>
> What if you never actually needed to use that query at all? What if you want to make it more complex before executing it? Relations give you that flexibility and make much more efficient use of your database's valuable time.

This means that each time you define a variable, `ActiveRecord` will *only* hit the db when it's needed.

Thus, you *could* get away with scoping your `@users` variable:

```
def index
  @users = User.all
end

#app/views/users/index.html.erb
<% roles = %i(admin call_user buy_user blocked_user) %>
<% roles.each do |role| %>
   <%= role %>
   <%= @users.where(role: role).each do |user| %>
      <%= user.name %>
   <% end %>
<% end %>
```

... or if you were using an `enum`:

```
#app/views/users/index.html.erb
<% User.roles.each do |role| %>
   <%= role %>
   <%= User.send(role).each do |user| %>
      <%= user.name %>
   <% end %>
<% end %>
```

---

**DB**

As described by `@Sasidaran`, the best way to achieve this is to let the database do the work.

Apart from his code, the best thing you can do is to make sure you're only hitting the database for the data you're going to use. Let the db server compute what's required, Rails should only be used as a conduit.